How can I get pyinstaller to create a onefile executable with multiple .py scripts?
On a Windows machine, I have modified my Spec file to point to my src path which includes my main python script and several imported scripts.  When I run the executable, it says it can't find 'settings.py' which is one of the imported scripts.
Here is my Analysis section of my spec file:
a = Analysis(
    ['c:\\Users\\name\\python_projects\\projectname\\src\\projectname\\main_script.py'],
    pathex=['c:\\Users\\name\\python_projects\\projectname\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('src\\projectname\\', 'src')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)

I've read the examples and the documentation and can't figure out why this is not working. I have no problem building python executables with pyinstaller using --onfile with a single .py script.

It turns out the information I've seen is incorrect.  You need to include the path to your imported scripts in the pathex portion of the spec file (or use --paths when building without a spec file.
a = Analysis(
    ['c:\\Users\\name\\python_projects\\projectname\\src\\projectname\\main_script.py'],
    pathex=['c:\\Users\\name\\python_projects\\projectname\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages', 'c:\\Users\\name\\python_projects\\projectname\\src\\projectname'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)

